# Wordpress Query with arrays

Tags: arrays, wordpress

I have a post query however I cannot get it to take into account the category IDs. What am I missing?

It takes into account the first two arrays, but the final one is just ignored.

```
                    <?php 
        $args = array(
            'meta_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'key' => 'packageID',
                    'value' => array('1', '2', '3'),
                    'compare' => 'IN',
                    'post_type'=>'post',
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                ),
                array(
                    'key' => 'Key_6',
                    'value' => 'Reportage',
                    'compare' => 'IN',
                ),
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'category',
                    'field' => 'term_id',
                    'cat' => array( '67, 84, 66, 73, 3549, 145, 101, 99, 100, 134, 92, 98' ),
                )
            ),              
        'orderby'  => 'meta_value_num',
        'meta_key' => 'wpfp_favorites',
        'order'    => 'DESC',
        'offset' => 0
        );
        query_posts($args); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your cat IDs to an array.

```
'cat' => array( '67, 84, 66, 73, 3549, 145, 101, 99, 100, 134, 92, 98' ),
```

Change:

```
'field' => 'ID',
```

To:

```
'field' => 'term_id',
```

Comment: Didn't seem to change anything :-(

Comment: I should have seen, please change  'cat' => array to  'terms' => array

Comment: I think the issue is around this section - 'meta_query' => array(
Changing it to - tax_query' => array(
Makes the category array work, but the other arrays break